# Why does this code keep returning a "variable might not have been initialized" error?

Tags: java

I'm new to coding with java, so excuse me if I come off a bit uninformed, but my code keeps returning this error for me:

```
Main.java:15: error: variable hold might not have been initialized
        return hold;
               ^
```

My code is as follows:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static double calcPostage(double ounces)
    {
        double hold;
        if ((ounces <= 10) && (ounces > 0))
            hold = 3;
        else if (ounces > 10)
            hold = ((ounces-10)*0.15)+3;
        else
            System.out.print("Invalid input.");
        return hold;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double hold;
        DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter how heavy your package is in ounces.\n");
        double ounces = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("It will cost " + form.format(calcPostage(ounces)) + " to mail your package.");
    }
}
```

There might be some other issues in that code as I haven't been able to successfully run it just yet, but I'd truly appreciate it if someone could help me out with this. Thanks!

Comment: Initialize it with a default value `double hold = 0.0;`

Comment: Well, for a local variable, *all code paths* must eventually initialize the value. Your `else` block doesn't.

Comment: Or, if `ounces <= 0` were truly invalid output and you do not want to initialize `hold`, you could have thrown an exception: `else { throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Ounces must be above 0");}`

Comment: Your IDE  must have warned you with a tiny red cross mark to the left of it and if you click that, your IDE can automatically put a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below code :

```
public static double calcPostage(double ounces)
{
    double hold;
    if ((ounces <= 10) && (ounces > 0))
        hold = 3;
    else if (ounces > 10)
        hold = ((ounces-10)*0.15)+3;
    else
        System.out.print("Invalid input.");
    return hold;
}
```

Suppose , if none of the conditions in "if" and "else if" are met, then `-- double type variable hold --` doesn't gets initialized. Hence you are receiving the error :

```
Main.java:15: error: variable hold might not have been initialized
    return hold;
           ^
```

So it is always better to initialize your variables to assign them a default value or an initial value.

Do this :

```
double hold = 0.0;
```

Answer (score -1):

condition where if and else if both condition do not get satisfied else print invalid input but hold in that case is not initialized .
try to put 
double hold=0.0; 
so that hold get initialized.